# Are there ways to prevent or slow down the development of white hair?

Tags: hair, aging

I am caucasian man. I am 32 years old. In the last times, a lot of white hairs have appeared in my head. I know this is not a serious health problem, but it makes me feeling older than actual I am. I know this process is quite normal in people with my characteristics. My question is if you know any product or methods that could delay or even revert the process.

Thank you very much in advance.